# How to use duplicate rows and conditions to update a column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, duplicates

I have duplicate data and giving a set of conditions I want to update a column with a "flag".
Original:

| A | B | C | D | aa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 4 | 7 | 15 | -99.0 |
| foo | 4 | 7 | 15 | 0.1 |
| bar | 5 | 9 | 3 | 14 |
| bar | 6 | 2 | 4 | 14 |

Add a flag field called "Keep":

| A | B | C | D | aa | Keep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 4 | 7 | 15 | -99.0 |  |
| foo | 4 | 7 | 15 | 0.1 |  |
| bar | 5 | 9 | 3 | 14 |  |
| bar | 6 | 2 | 4 | 14 |  |

If there is a duplicate (these are sorted by A, B, C; duplicate defined as if A0=A1 & B0=B1 & C0=C1 & D0=D1) then look at column "aa" and if aa0>aa1, assign a 1 to "Keep" for the Keep0 cell and assign a 0 to the Keep1 cell.  If no duplicate, assign a 1 to keep it in the "Keep" column:

| A | B | C | D | aa | Keep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 4 | 7 | 15 | -99.0 | 0 |
| foo | 4 | 7 | 15 | 0.1 | 1 |
| bar | 5 | 9 | 3 | 14 | 1 |
| bar | 6 | 2 | 4 | 14 | 1 |

The code I have tried is by using a duplicate dictionary and then a 'for' loop but for some reason it says that the aa0 and aa1 are different values (0,1) but then it just assigns 1's even if they are duplicate and meet all the if statements?

```
dup_dict = []
flg = False
for i in range(npts-1):
    d2 = 0.0
    for idir in range(2,-2,-1):
        if (idir==-1 and d2 <= d2tol ):
            dup_dict.append([i,i+1,d2])
            break
        d = np.abs(xyz[i,idir]-xyz[i+1,idir])
        if (d > dtol):
            break
        d2 = d2 + d ** 2
print('Total Duplicates Found: %d'%(len(dup_dict)))

df['Keep'] = np.ones(len(df.index))
fmtlist = ['%s','%0.5f','%0.5f','%0.5f','%0.5f','%d','%s']
fl = open('dup_mm_acq_comb.log','w')
fl.write(','.join(['dhid','x','y','z','aufa','Keep'])+'\n')
for i0,i1,d in dup_dict:
    aa0 = df['aa'].values[i0]
    aa1 = df['aa'].values[i1]

    if aa0 > aa1:
        df.loc[i0,'Keep'] = 1
        df.loc[i1,'Keep'] = 0
    if  aa0 <= aa1:
        df.loc[i0,'Keep'] = 0
        df.loc[i1,'Keep'] = 1
    #print(df['A'].values[i0],df['A'].values[i1],df['Keep'].values[i0],df['Keep'].values[i1])    
    a = df[['A','B','C','D','aa','Keep']].values[[i0,i1],:]
    np.savetxt(fl,a,fmt=fmtlist,delimiter=',')
fl.close()
```

Output:

```
print (i1)   -->   2

print (i0)   -->   1

print (aa1)  -->   0.1

print (aa0)  -->   -99.0

print(df.at[i0,'Keep']) -->  0.0 

print(df.at[i1,'Keep']) -->  1.0

print(a)  -->
[['foo' 4 7 15 -99.0 1.0]
 ['foo' 4 7 15   0.1 1.0]]
```

the first one should say 0.0 instead of 1.0 since 0.1>-99.0
Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `idxmax` to find the index of the highest value in the group and set to 1:

```py
COLS = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

df["Keep"] = 0
df.loc[df.groupby(COLS)["aa"].apply(lambda x: x.idxmax()).values, "Keep"] = 1
```

```py
>>> df
     A  B  C   D    aa  Keep
0  foo  4  7  15 -99.0     0
1  foo  4  7  15   0.1     1
2  bar  5  9   3  14.0     1
3  bar  6  2   4  14.0     1
```

Comment: what happens if the two duplicate values are -99.0 or the same value 0.1 or something.  Will it just pick one or ?

Comment: `idxmax` returns the index of the maximum so if the highest value is duplicated, the first index is returned. It does not matter for other lower values.

Answer (score 0):

After 5 days, I figured out I was missing one line before the dup_dict[].  I was missing:
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)

Adding that makes the script work and flag the Keep variable.  I'm open to anymore solutions, especially ones that are shorter (similar to Corralien above).